# Verilog design to display character using "16x2 Character Display" IP from Quartus IP Library

Tags: verilog, lcd, intel-fpga

I was trying to display a single character on 16x2 display. I created simple Verilog design for "Altera Cyclone V Development Kit". In the project I used "16x2 Character Display" IP from the library available in Quartus IDE. This IP uses Avalon interface, so I created simple state machine which takes care of Avalon interface timing according to "Slave Write Transfer with Variable Wait-States" from the Avalon spec. BDW, this IP implements old version of Avalon spec  because it leverages chipselect signal (it is deprecated in newer specs). Unfortunately the code below does not work. It resets the display, but the character "B" does not appear on LCD.
What am I doing wrong?

```
module lcd_display(clk50, lcd_data, lcd_en, lcd_rs, lcd_rw);

input clk50;
output [7:0] lcd_data;
output lcd_en, lcd_rs, lcd_rw;


parameter   S_BEGIN         = 3'h0,
                S_RESET             = 3'h1,
                S_WAIT_RESET    = 3'h2,
                S_DEASSERT_CS   = 3'h3,
                S_CLEAN_CS      = 3'h4,
                S_SET_DATA      = 3'h5,
                S_WAIT_WRITE    = 3'h6,
                S_END           = 3'h7;


reg [2:0] state = S_BEGIN, next_state;
reg [7:0] writedata;
reg reset, address, chipselect, write;

wire waitrequest;

lcd lcd1(
    .LCD_DATA(lcd_data),
    .LCD_EN(lcd_en),
    .LCD_RS(lcd_rs),
    .LCD_RW(lcd_rw),
    
    .address(address),
    .chipselect(chipselect),
    .read(1'b0), // not used
    .clk(clk50),
    .writedata(writedata),
    .write(write),
    .reset(reset),
    .waitrequest(waitrequest)
    );
    
always @(posedge clk50)
begin
    state <= next_state;
end
    
always @(*) begin
    case (state)
        S_BEGIN:
            next_state = S_RESET;
        
        S_RESET:
            next_state = S_WAIT_RESET;
        
        S_WAIT_RESET:
            if (waitrequest)
                next_state = S_WAIT_RESET;
            else
                next_state = S_DEASSERT_CS;
        
        S_DEASSERT_CS:
            next_state = S_SET_DATA;
        
        S_SET_DATA:
            next_state = S_WAIT_WRITE;

        S_WAIT_WRITE:
            if (waitrequest)
                next_state = S_WAIT_WRITE;
            else
                next_state = S_END;
        
        S_END:
            next_state = S_END;
        
        default:
        begin
            next_state = S_BEGIN;
        end
    endcase
end

always @(*)
begin
    if (state == S_RESET)
        reset = 1'b1;
    else
        reset = 1'b0;   
end

always @(*)
begin
    if (    state == S_RESET | state == S_WAIT_RESET |
            state == S_SET_DATA | state == S_WAIT_WRITE)
        chipselect = 1'b1;
    else
        chipselect = 1'b0;
end

always @(*)
begin
    if (state == S_DEASSERT_CS | state == S_SET_DATA | state == S_WAIT_WRITE)
    begin
        write = 1'b1;
        writedata = "B";
        address = 1'b1;
    end 
    else
    begin
        write = 1'b0;
        writedata = 0;
        address = 1'b0;
    end
end
```

endmodule

Comment: HAve you simulated your design?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm a beginner and I need to learn how to create a test bench. I just did simple debugging by turning on and off LEDs on the board. It seems like it is stuck at S_WAIT_WRITE which in turn is caused by LCD's "busy flag" being set.

Comment: once you get into the  S_END state, how do you get out?

Comment: @toolic - I don't . I just wanted to display one character as a test. In my real design this will not be like that.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I did the simulation and signals look ok. As far as I can tell, the sequence is correct.